# Android : No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, surfaceview

I try to add "rank this app" button in my app

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(goToMarket);
```

then I get Error "Android : No Activity found to handle Intent"

BTW : I use SurfaceView I don't know if it is important

Comment: Do you want to give a rating to this app??

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because:

1. You're on a device where Google Play is not installed (for example, a device that's not an official Android device).
2. Google Play is installed, but disabled (make sure it's not disabled in the settings menu).
3. It's a rooted device and there is something nonstandard interfering with the intent launch/match mechanism.

Comment: Just a note that the emulator doesn't have Google Play, so that would fit point 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add try catch to prevent from crash, if there is no market app is installed in your device

```
try
{
context.startActivity(goToMarket);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//Show Toast
}
```